# Error while syncing project with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Please, I have the error below and I can not identify the cause:

Error:(26, 0) Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler. Open File

---

FileNotFoundException: Entry fileTemplates//code/Google Test Fixture SetUp Method.cc.ft not found in /C:/Program%20Files/Android/Android%20Studio/lib/idea.jar

The google-services.json file is within the project, as documented:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSUqS.png)

build.gradle (Projeto):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn2il.png)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
  allprojects {
   repositories {
      jcenter()
   }
 }
 task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

build.gradle (App):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjSf6.png)

```
enter code here
```

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "br.com.firebase.testes_firebase"
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
  }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Print Screen Android:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NcWj.png)

Comment: Have you added `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` as the last line in your build.gradle file?

Answer (score 1):

Add google repository to your project and sync.

`allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        // ...
        google() // Google's Maven repository
    }
}`